# Can't access class object variable

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop, variables

I'm using Swift 2 to make a function that creates a bunch of objects from a class I wrote.

Now, the problem is that when I'm adding a new object I have no problem, I checked multiple times both from the function and from the init() function that it stores the data. (Printing self.myVariable from the init() function works).

However, when later I go to retrive my variable for example like

```
 if let dog: Animal? = Animal.init(id : "12345"){
print(dog?.legs)}
```

That prints nil, even though I checked in the Animal class and it successfully initialized the Animal object "dog".

If anybody has any idea why this is happening that would be really useful and appreciated.

Here's the link to the actual code, the Animal class was just an example but this is probably more useful : [Class](http://pastebin.com/PYmaHPDD) & [Function](http://pastebin.com/S76460cz)

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the Animal class? The problem is likely to be there, rather than the code you've shown here.

Comment: why is dog of type `Animal?`? Please show more of the surrounding code.

Comment: This is the code for the function : [link](http://pastebin.com/S76460cz) and this is the code for the class : [link](http://pastebin.com/PYmaHPDD) . The Animal class was just an example to simplify but I guess I didn't exaplain that well! Let me know if you have any questions! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to your class code [here](http://pastebin.com/PYmaHPDD).

Inside of your init function you are never setting the class variable, id. You could set it as follows:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id as String) { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)

        }
        else {
            if let atm = object {
            print("ATM found")
            self.bank = atm["bank"] as? NSString
            self.type = atm["type"] as? NSNumber
            self.location = atm["location"] as? PFGeoPoint
            self.description = atm["description"] as? NSString

            // Set id to whatever you'd like here
            self.id = atm.objectId!
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's true, thanks. Now I added the line to set the id but it's still returning a null when extracting a variable from the object "result" I created inside the function ATMsAroundMe(myLocation : PFGeoPoint). Do you know what else might be causing the issue?

Comment: Great! 

Because you're initializing an optional type (let result : ATM?), that allows the value to be nil. Most likely the entire result:ATM? instance is nil. So most likely your ATM.init() is failing.

Comment: Could my init() be failing even though some of the print statement I put in it to test it work properly and display the downloaded information about the item?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PFQuery but since it's using a completion handler, it is responding asynchronously to the call to getObjectInBackground.  That means that when you get your object from init(id:...) it does not yet have a value in the bank field.   So result?.bank prints nil because bank is nil, not because result is nil.

Once the completion handler is executed, bank will have its value (if no error occurred) but it would be unlikely that this would happen in the short time between init() and your let result : ATM? = ... condition.

Comment: Okay, I think I get that but my init(id: ...) function should fill up the object with various data retrieved from the server through Parse.com.
If you're saying that it takes more time to retrieve the data from the server than to initialize the object I get that, but how would I fix that so that it takes as long as it has too but I get a "filled" object at the end, with all the parameters already downloaded from the server?

Comment: You will need to structure your code differently.   An asynchronous interaction requires that the design of your ATM object also provides its services asynchronously.  At the very least it must provide its own completion handler so that the calling code can be notified when the initialization is complete.   You will not be able to return a fully initialized object to the caller.   To give you an idea of the time difference,  network calls are measured in milliseconds.  Initializing an object can be as fast a as few nanoseconds.